# Postgres sequence not generating sequential values

Tags: postgresql

I have this sequence defined in postgres 9.6.11 running in AWS RDS

```
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS org.my_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS org.my_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  NO MAXVALUE
  START 1
  CACHE 20;
```

This sequence is then invoked by Hibernate sequence generation strategy from within Spring boot application deployed within Docker container. The values generated are shown below. I am completely confused by why the values generated by this sequence are all over the place. I also noticed that every time I shut down my docker container, restart it, and test the application again, the values start to come from a whole different range. Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

-28
-27
-26
-25
-8
-7
1
2
52
53
72
92
93
94
112
113
132
133
152
172
192
193
212

Comment: Seems to be the same as your previous question [Postgres 9.6.11 sequence in RDS generating negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956983/postgres-9-6-11-sequence-in-rds-generating-negative-values)? Please [edit] it to add/remove information instead of reposting.

Comment: I have deleted that old question, as I was not getting any response on it.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain the negative values - perhaps someone has ignored the default values.

But the gaps are clear:

- Sequences are not transactional in the way that a `ROLLBACK` does not reset the sequence. So any value that has been generated will be lostif the `INSERT` that wanted to use that value fails.

  That is a feature, not a bug, because it allows fast operation.
- If you use `CACHE 20` performance is further improved, because now each database session gets 20 values whenever it requests a new number from the sequence. The session caches these values and doesn't have to access the sequence for the next couple of times it needs a value.

  Of course these cached values die with the session, so if a database session requests a sequence value and then terminates, there will be a gap of 20 values.

This is all perfectly fine and as expected.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, I read up a bit on postgres sessions in their architectural documentation. Now it makes sense why the block of ids changes when I restart my docker container. However, the negative values still do not make sense.